# Significance of resultData

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this already written code by someone else to add new value on UI.Its using Java Script, AJAX and Json which I am totally new to.

I am not getting how they are fetching the variable `resultData` in done(function())

Code snippet is:

```
$.ajax(url, {
        cache : false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {
            depth: 10,
            readSystemFields: true,
            recordStates :'ACTIVE,PENDING'
        }
    }).done(function(resultData)
```

They are using it to get some values like:

```
$("#componentSectionFieldValue" +  {{rowidObject}} + (i + "" +j) + "b2bFinancial" ).append( $('<a />').attr('href', 'mailto:' + mdm.entity360view.helperUtil.getData(**resultData**, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].coValue,
 mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].defaultValue,
 mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].defaultKey, mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].defaultKeyValue, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].coFieldValues, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].concatenateWith,  
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].getStrategy) ).text(mdm.entity360view.helperUtil.getData(resultData, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].coValue, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].defaultValue, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].defaultKey, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].defaultKeyValue, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].coFieldValues, 
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].concatenateWith,  
mdm.entity360view.ConfigContour.widgets.b2b.financal.section[i].field[j].getStrategy)) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is a very good resource to see how done works with jquery ajax.

> `jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {})`;
>   An alternative construct to the success callback option, refer to deferred.done() for implementation details.

Then go through the documentation on [done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

> Since the jQuery.get method returns a jqXHR object, which is derived
>   from a Deferred object, we can attach a success callback using the
>   .done() method.
>
> ```
> $.get( "test.php" ).done(function() {
>   alert( "$.get succeeded" );
> });
> ```

Hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I went through it, its helpful.